# Ngrx Store: Is there any way to get the difference in states after some action is executed

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I am using ngrx store for a complex store structure as shown in code:

model.ts

```
export interface ITableState {
    tables: ITables,
    selectedTableId: number
}

export interface ITables {
    [id: number]: ITable
}


export interface ITable {
    menus: IMenus,
    selectedMenuId: string
}

export interface IMenus {
    dishId: number,
    dishName: string
}
```

reducer.ts

```
    case tables.ActionTypes.ADD_MENU: {
      var menuToAdd = <IAddMenu>action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        tables: {
          ...state.tables,
          [menuToAdd.tableId]: {
            ...state.tables[menuToAdd.tableId],
            menus: {
              ...state.tables[menuToAdd.tableId].menus,
              [menuToAdd.menuId]: menuToAdd.menu
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am subscribing this store as below:

```
    export const getTableStructureState = (state: State) => state.table;

public tableStructureState$ = this.appState$.select(store.getTableStructureState);

 this.tableSandbox.tableStructureState$.subscribe(tableDataState => {
 console.log(tableDataState.tables[tableDataState.selectedTableId].menus)
 });
```

So on executing the action ADD_MENU, I get all menus in the store.
**But my question is**

> if suppose I added two menus and then again I added the third menu is
>   there any way by which I can get to know which was the last menu
>   added. or in simple words what changes occurred in the state.

I have searched for it a lot, but didn't got any solution.
Please let me know if its possible or not.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: couldn't you just log your actions? looking at last action (of desired type) payload would show you what menus you've added in that action.

Comment: Yes, I can surely log them. but I need some subscription kind of way (if possible) to get what changed because I have to do some processing with the data that changed.

Comment: you could probably utilize subject/behaviorsubject which you fill with data from actions (in effects) and to which you subscribe from places where you want to use it

Comment: Thanks.. but Can you please let me know how this can be done. Can you please share some link or example on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep into your store a `lastChange` property for example, or an history of changes...
Then create a selector which return the last change. 
Like this, you'll use the powerful of NgRx.

```
export interface ITableState {
    tables: ITables,
    selectedTableId: number,
    lastChange: IAddMenu
}

case tables.ActionTypes.ADD_MENU: {
  var menuToAdd = <IAddMenu>action.payload;

  // what was the previous change ?
  const previousChange = state.lastChange;
  if (previousChange.xxxxx) {
    // do something depending on last change... 
    ...
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    tables: {
      ...
    },
    lastChange: action.payload  // store new last change
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.